# Cannot Access phpmyadmin error

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I cannot access phpmyadmin. I just want to access phpmyadmin. I am not starting any codes yet. I just basically want to access phpmyadmin. Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G97VM.png). i already search for possible solutions but no changes.

Comment: Please, provide the mysql configuration info.On what port is running mysql?

Comment: port is 3307
apache port is 443,8080

Comment: Have you tried to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Answer (score 0):

If your operating system is Windows 7:

1. go to control panel -> Administrative Tools -> Services
2. find mysql then right-click, click start

If your operating system is Linux (Ubuntu):

3. in terminal type this command: sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start

Good Luck